# Does Tensorflow has the data type like set() in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to implement an operation that extract all different elements in a Tensorflow tensor. In python, I usually use `set(array)`, but I don't know if there is any data type like `set` in `Tensorflow` or any functions with the same effect.

Comment: Have you looked at [`tf.sets`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sets)? Depends on what do you want to achieve, but in some cases you can use [`tf.TensorArray()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray) to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: @Vlad, yeah, there are some functions about the operations of set, but I still don't have an idea about how to obtain all different elements in an tensorflow array through a tensorflow api.

Comment: You want to get all unique elements from a tensor?

Comment: @Vlad yes，just like the function set() in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all unique elements from tensor use `tf.unique()`. First you reshape the tensor to be of `rank=1` and then you apply `tf.unique()`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.], [3., 4., 5.]], dtype=tf.float32)
flatten = tf.reshape(tensor, [-1]) 
unique = tf.unique(flatten)[0]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(unique.eval()) # [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
```